# Change caret blinking speed in whole system Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10

Is there any way to change the speed of caret blinking, not only in particular application, but for whole system.

For example in macOS it's possible with this command.

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod -float 1000
```

Maybe there's some way in Ubuntu also.
Thanks in advance.

Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible if by caret you mean cursor.

Go to Settings > Universal Access > Typing >Cursor Blinking and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will show a slider which you can adjust to suit your needs.

[image]

[image]

[reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-cursor-blink.html.en)

Comment: If this answers the question for you, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) which will make it easier for someone else with the same question to find. Thank you.